# How to get the closest time to current time from an array of dates ? iOS, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdate

I am trying to get the closest time (hours and minutes) to current time (hours and minutes) from an array of Date objects.

What I want is not to compare and find the closest date but time (hours and minutes only). Is there any iOS way / Swfit 3 to do that efficiently?

**Edit:**
The closest time is the time by "moving forward" clockwise, not backwards.

**Edit2:**
Here is a sample:

```
import Foundation

let userCalendar = Calendar.current

var firstDateComponents = DateComponents()
firstDateComponents.year = 2017
firstDateComponents.month = 1
firstDateComponents.day = 1
firstDateComponents.hour = 23
firstDateComponents.minute = 50
let firstDate = userCalendar.date(from: firstDateComponents)

var secondDateComponents = DateComponents()
secondDateComponents.year = 2016
secondDateComponents.month = 12
secondDateComponents.day = 24
secondDateComponents.hour = 23
secondDateComponents.minute = 55
let secondDate = userCalendar.date(from: secondDateComponents)

var thirdDateComponents = DateComponents()
thirdDateComponents.year = 2017
thirdDateComponents.month = 3
thirdDateComponents.day = 1
thirdDateComponents.hour = 0
thirdDateComponents.minute = 30
let thirdDate = userCalendar.date(from: thirdDateComponents)

var fourthDateComponents = DateComponents()
fourthDateComponents.year = 2017
fourthDateComponents.month = 3
fourthDateComponents.day = 1
fourthDateComponents.hour = 4
fourthDateComponents.minute = 20
let fourthDate = userCalendar.date(from: fourthDateComponents)

var currentDateComponents = DateComponents()
currentDateComponents.year = 2017
currentDateComponents.month = 3
currentDateComponents.day = 2
currentDateComponents.hour = 0
currentDateComponents.minute = 10

let currentDate = userCalendar.date(from: currentDateComponents)
let dates = [firstDate, secondDate, thirdDate, fourthDate]
```

The expected result for this example would be a data structure containing (12:30 AM), the third date.

**Edit3:**
Trying to get to the solution:

To get the time components and strip irrelevant Date information:

```
let dateComponentsFromDates = dates.map { date -> DateComponents in
    let dateComponents = DateComponents(calendar: userCalendar, timeZone: nil, era: nil, year: nil, month: nil, day: nil, hour: userCalendar.component(.hour, from: date!), minute: userCalendar.component(.minute, from: date!), second: nil, nanosecond: nil, weekday: nil, weekdayOrdinal: nil, quarter: nil, weekOfMonth: nil, weekOfYear: nil, yearForWeekOfYear: nil)
    return dateComponents
}
```

Comment: I believe they want to compare the hours/minutes, ignoring the day/month/year component; ie. If it is now 10:20, then 10:19 on Sunday is "closer" than 9:20 on Tuesday ('today')

Comment: Is `23:59` closer to `0:01` or `23:50`?

Comment: It seems you have to compare dates and on Swift 3 comparing dates is so easy because its Comparable & Equatable

Comment: What is the exact input format? Is the array sorted or not? What if two times are equally close? What about "wrap around" at midnight (what kennytm said)? How large is the array – is efficiency really relevant? –  What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you for questions guys. @MartinR I want to find the closest time moving "forward" by comparing times from those dates. The array consists of Date objects. Those dates might have different date and time. The array consists of about 10 elements. Paulw11 Exactly this is my intention. kennytm 23:59 is closer to 0:01. abdullahselek I haven't figured out yet how to compare the times.

Comment: @tommagellancook: If the array contains `Date` objects then your statement *"The dates can be in AM/PM format or 24h format ..."* makes no sense. A `Date` is an absolute point in time and has no format. A *concrete* example with input data and expected result would be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR I've removed it.

Comment: And what would be the expected result in your example, and why?

Comment: @MartinR See the edit, the expected result would be a data structure containing 12:30AM, this is the closest time specified in the currentDate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply sort your list of dates based on it's offset from the current time, using a calendar and date components we can make sure we only look at the hour and minute components of the date:

```
var dates = [Date]()
// assume somehow this array is populated
let cal = Calendar.current
let nowComponents = cal.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.hour, Calendar.Component.minute], from: Date())
let nowMinsIntoDay = (nowComponents.hour ?? 0) * 60 + (nowComponents.minute ?? 0)
// Create a new list of tuples including the date and the minutes from now
let datesWithMinsFromNow = dates.map { (date) -> (Date, Int) in
    let comp = cal.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.hour, Calendar.Component.minute], from: date)
    let minsFromNow = (comp.hour ?? 0) * 60 + (comp.minute ?? 0) - nowMinsIntoDay
    return (date, minsFromNow)
}
// Filter out any pairs that are earlier in the day than now
let datesLaterThanNow = datesWithMinsFromNow.filter { return $0.1 >= 0 }
// Sort the remaining items
let sortedDates = datesLaterThanNow.sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }
// Take the first item
let closest = sortedDates.first?.0 // closest should now be a `Date` object
```

Comment: This will compare also the date, not only the time.

Comment: @GeorgeGreen thanks. I wish I had clarified my question more. By the closest time I meant that if we have for example current time 12:23 PM and it the array there is 6:48AM, 12:05 PM and 4:01AM then closest time to that time would be 4:01 AM, so that the closest time is calculated "forward", not backwards.

Comment: @tommagellancook Ah, so what you want is the "next" time from now, in the array?

Comment: @GeorgeGreen I'm impressed with the use of of the tuple. I have run the code however the result is not what is expected. I need to only consider the time (hours and minutes) and disregard the rest of the date parts.

Comment: @tommagellancook Sorry about that, I forgot that we don't want the difference between the two, but in fact the difference in absolute hours from the day's origin. See updated for a hopefully working solution :)

Comment: @GeorgeGreen First of all thanks. Could you run your code in a playground against my sample data from the question, and as a current date use the currentDate provided in the sample? What are your results?

Comment: @tommagellancook With your test data this correctly selects March 1st 0030hrs (third date)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138053/discussion-between-tommagellancook-and-george-green).

Comment: hey, can you share updated answer. i am not getting corrent solution

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the current time to miliseconds and check for each date if its miliseconds is closer to the current time's miliseconds.

Thats how i would do so:

```
let dates = [Date]()
let currentDate = Date()
var closestMiliseconds = nowDate.currentTimeInMiliseconds()
for date in dates {
    if currentDate.currentTimeInMiliseconds() - date.currentTimeInMiliseconds() < closestMiliseconds {
        closestMiliseconds = Int(date.currentTimeInMiliseconds())
    }
}

let closestDate = closestMiliseconds.dateFromMilliseconds()
```

Thats the currentTimeInMiliseconds() Function:

```
func currentTimeInMiliseconds() -> Int64 {
   let since1970 = self.timeIntervalSince1970
   return Int64(since1970 * 1000)
}
```

And thats the dateFromMilliseconds() Function:

```
 func dateFromMilliseconds() -> Date {
   return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(self)/1000)
 }
```

Comment: thanks for trying to tackle the problem. Could you run your code in a playground against my sample data from the question, and as a current date use the currentDate provided in the sample? What are your results?

Comment: @tommagellancook i tried that.
I got the forth date as the closest one, is it the right one?